# Is learning rate automatically decreased between passes when vw LDA is run with `--save_resume`

Tags: lda, vowpalwabbit

vowpal wabbit (`vw`) supports out-of-core learning with `--save_resume`. This is what the `--help` options tells the end user about the `--save_resume` option:

```
--save_resume                         save extra state so learning can be 
                                        resumed later with new data
```

I have a large living data set, currently hundreds of millions documents sorted into 1024 batches, and my goal is train a LDA-model on all batches, and for that purpose I run a script that invokes `vw` like this (*Nota bene* I do not set `--passes`, so each data point is only seen once).

Initial invokation:

```
vw -d clean.txt --lda 100 --lda_D 307000000 -f weights --readable_model lda.model.vw
```

Subsequent invocations (the content of clean.txt is changed between invocations):

```
vw -d clean.txt --lda 100 --lda_D 307000000 --save_resume -i weights -f weights --readable_model lda.model.vw
```

I have successfully run all batches through vw this way, but from the output given by `vw` in each invocation, it seems the learning rate never drops, it always looks like this:

```
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
```

I would have guessed that the learning rate is saved when `--save_resume` is requested, and that `vw` automatically decreases the learning rate as it sees more data, but this does not seem to be the case, right?

Do you have to manage the learning rate manually with vowpal wabbit?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that LDA has a learn rate thats computed based on (but stored separately from) the global learning rate. LDA's learning/decay rates don't appear to be printed anywhere, so you wouldn't see them in the logs.

https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/lda_core.cc#L892

Comment: When you write that the learning rate (of LDA) is "stored", do you mean stored on disk, and picked up when `--save_resume` is used? Or do you mean "stored" in a different variable during program execution and then not saved to disk?